# Clicar em botão e abrir lista

Tags: php, javascript

Estou tentando fazer com que o usuário consiga, ao clicar no botão, ver todo o conteúdo do banco de dados e quando não fica em exibição 6 produtos (isso já está ok), mas a parte do botão estou quebrando a cabeça e não sei onde estou errando. Segue *script*:

Essa é a parte do código que exibe 6 itens (busco no BD com um LIMIT 6):

```
<div class="col-md-9">

    <div class="row"> 

        <?php 
        $dao=new produtoDAO($conexao);
        $produtos = $dao->listaContainer();
        foreach($produtos as $produto) : 
        ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card card-product card-plain">

                <div class="image">
                    <a href="precompra.php?id=<?=$produto->getId()?>">
                        <img src="../cadastro/fotos/<?=$produto->getFoto() ?>" alt="foto"/>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <a href="#">
                        <h4 class="title"><?=$produto->getMarca()->getNome() ?></h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="description">
                      <?=$produto->getDescricao() ?>
                    </p>
                    <div class="footer">
                        <span class="price"> R&dollar;<?=$produto->getPreco() ?></span>                     
                    </div>

                </div><!-- card-product -->

            </div> <!-- end card -->

        </div><!-- col-md-4 -->
        <?php endforeach?>
```

Esta é a parte do código referente ao Botão de abrir mais, utilizei display none, função javascript mas não consegui fazer funcionar...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#successBtn").click(function(){
if($("#produtos").css('display') === 'none'){
  $("#produtos").show();
}else{
  $("#produtos").hide();
}

});
});
</script>

                              <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4" >                      
                              <button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Abrindo..." class="btn btn-default btn-round" id="successBtn" data-toggle="morphing" data-rotation-color="red" >Mais Produtos...
                               </button>
                              </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4"  style="display:none;" id="produtos">

                            <?php 
                            $dao=new produtoDAO($conexao);
                            $produtos = $dao->listaProdutos();
                            foreach($produtos as $produto) : 
                              ?>
                            <div class="card card-product card-plain">

                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="precompra.php?id=<?=$produto->getId()?>">
                                <img src="../cadastro/fotos/<?=$produto->getFoto() ?>" alt="foto"/>
                            </a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="content">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <h4 class="title"><?=$produto->getMarca()->getNome() ?></h4>
                                    </a>
                                    <p class="description">
                                      <?=$produto->getDescricao() ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <span class="price"> R&dollar;<?=$produto->getPreco() ?></span>                     
                                    </div>

                                <</div> <!-- end card -->




                         </div><!-- col-md-4 -->

                             <?php endforeach?>

                         </div>

                    </div><!-- row -->
                </div><!-- col-md-9 -->


           </div><!-- row -->
       </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- section -->
```

Comment: Acho que você só esqueceu o seletor de ID `#` no click do  `successBtn`  - `$("#successBtn").click(function () { ... }`

Comment: Obrigado Pedro, alterei e inclui o seletor mas mesmo assim nada. O botão não está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar dessa forma e ver se resolve.

```
$(function() {
    $("#successBtn").click(function(){
        $("#produtos").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Exemplo funcional.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#successBtn").click(function(){
    if($("#produtos").css('display') === 'none'){
      $("#produtos").show();
    }else{
      $("#produtos").hide();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="mostrar produtos" id="successBtn">
<div id="produtos" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li>Biscoito</li>
<li>Salgadinho</li>
<li>Refrigerante</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mateus fiz a alteração que me sugeriu mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Tente usar o show() e hide() do jQuery, show() para mostrar, hide() para esconder: `jQuery('#produtos').show();`

Comment: oi Mateus alterei e nada. O botão fica na condição "abrindo" e não abre a lista de produtos. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Tem como verificar se entra na função de click ?

Comment: jQuery.fn.offset = function( options ) {
 if ( arguments.length ) {
  return options === undefined ?
   this :
   this.each(function( i ) {
    jQuery.offset.setOffset( this, options, i );
   });
 }

Comment: eu achei essa função offset no arquivo jquery.1.10.2.js seria isso? ou se não como eu verifico se está entrando na função de click?

Comment: Você pode debugar com console.log() e verificar se apareceu em seu console do browser, exemplo :     $("#successBtn").click(function(){console.log('entrou');
        $("#produtos").show();
    });

Comment: Mateus não aparece no console

Comment: Editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo funcional, pode se basear por ele.

Comment: Mateus, fiz a alteração na minha pergunta conforme me orientou veja lá emcima. O display: none está funcionando (não está listando) então está certo a parte de esconder a listagem, O botão não está funcionando ainda, ele fica executando aquele morphing. Acredito que a função não está executando mesmo indicando o id do buttonSuccess. Nossa ta complicado mesmo. Você pode me ajudar a encontrar esse erro?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60084/discussion-between-mateus-veloso-and-sergio-guerjik).